# Bootstrap date field input value set using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

This is my bootstrap input field,

```
<input class="form-control" id="date" required="required" name="date" type="date">
```

I want to set date field value after some event using jquery,

```
// this is a date string return from database
var data = 2019-05-06 00:00:00 ;
$('#date').val(data);
```

but it's not set the value in bootstrap date picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datepicker` [update](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update)

> Update the datepicker with given arguments or the current input value.
>   The arguments can be either an array of strings, an array of Date
>   objects, multiples strings or multiples Date objects. If date
>   arguments are provided and they are Date objects, it is assumed to be
>   “local” Date objects, and will be converted to UTC for internal use.

Sample:

```
var data = "2019-05-06 00:00:00";
//data is a string
$(".datepicker").datepicker("update", data);
```

---

**UPDATE** Setting up a date type html

```js
var data = "2019-05-06 00:00:00";
document.getElementById("date").valueAsDate = new Date(data);
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="date" required="required" name="date" type="date">
```

Comment: I really don't want to use datepicker library. I wanted to use bootstrap built in date field. can you tell me why my solution doesn't work ?

Comment: This is from bootstrap @Md.SukelAli

Comment: If you are trying to setup value for html date type, I added a sample @Md.SukelAli

Comment: Yes ! I am looking for this solution.

Comment: Cool! Happy to help :)

Comment: By the way why it isn't set using `$('#date').val(data);` ?

Comment: I think jQuery `val()` is setting the `value` of the DOM. We need to set `valueAsDate` for date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var data = '2019-05-06 00:00:00';

$('#date').datepicker("update", data);
```